Is a PostgreSQL-Immutable Function safe to use with a Table-Parameter whose definition can change?
I have an Immutable Function that takes a Table as parameter
CREATE TABLE playground.t_test (
  c1 INTEGER,
  c2 INTEGER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION playground.f_test (
  test playground.t_test
)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE 'sql'
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
LEAKPROOF
PARALLEL SAFE
COST 100
AS
$body$
select
  to_jsonb(test);
$body$;

If the metadata of the table "playground.t_test" Changes, for example, if a new column is added. Will the Function regognize this as change and change the result in the next call?
I use PostgreSQL 14
I tried testing it myself, i added a timestamp to the result in the function body like this:
select
  to_jsonb(test) || jsonb_build_object('now', current_timestamp); -- I KNOW THIS IS NOT IMMUTABLE

Despite being immutable, the function generates me a new result with the new timestamp, every time i call the function. so i can't seem to be able to generate a proper testcase. Hence here i am :-)

In some cases, PostgreSQL can detect if an IMMUTABLE function is not immutable. For example, if you try to run a DML statement in an IMMUTABLE function, PostgreSQL will protest:
CREATE FUNCTION imm(integer) RETURNS void
   IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql
   AS 'INSERT INTO tab VALUES ($1)';

SELECT imm(5);
ERROR:  INSERT is not allowed in a non-volatile function
CONTEXT:  SQL function "imm" during startup

But in general, PostgreSQL doesn't invest a lot of effort to ascertain that an IMMUTABLE function really is immutable. If you define a function as IMMUTABLE, PostgreSQL simply believes you. It is the responsibility of the user to declare a function as IMMUTABLE only if it really lives up to the promise.
If you define an IMMUTABLE function that really isn't, bad things can happen. For example, you can use that function in an index definition. But if the function fails to keep the promise, like your modified function, the index will automatically become corrupted. In that case, you have only yourself to blame for the ensuing problems.
Now, is your original function definition OK? As you correctly observe, the function is not guaranteed to be immutable. If you change the table definition, the function will return different results than before.
Still, it is acceptable to declare such a function IMMUTABLE if you promise never to change the table definition. PostgreSQL has no way to enforce that, it is your responsibility.
Essentially, PostgreSQL allows such definitions because they can be really useful (e.g. for indexes).  The benefits outweigh the dangers.  It is up to the user to use that feature responsibly.

IMMUTABLE means: the same input doesnt trigger the function again and instead uses a prestored-value. I got that. But the input is by definition different if the definition of the table chages. My question is: Does the IMMUTABLE function respect that and produce a new result in that case? In my understanding it should, because a new column in the table definition does change the imput, albeit the the name of the data-type (= the table name) does not change.

You misunderstand IMMUTABLE. Such functions are executed every time, just like other functions. There is no cache for the results. One effect of IMMUTABLE is that you can use the function in a index definition. Another effect is that the optimizer can cut some corners: for example, if you use immutable_function('constant') in your statement, the optimizer can evaluate the function at query planning time.

Okay, got it. But to clarify: wouldnt't a change in the table definition change the argument value passed to the function? From the documentiaion: "IMMUTABLE indicates that the function cannot modify the database and always returns the same result when given the same argument values"

Yes, you could say that.

So, by that assumption, wouldn’t that make my function immutable?

That is debatable, and I don't have a clear-cut answer. What if you use NULL::playground.t_test as argument? The physical value passed will be identical, but you could say it is different, because the type has changed. Then you could say that if I consider the result different, then the argument was different, so it is still immutable. But what if you just use NULL as an argument, and the cast to playground.t_test happens implicitly? One could argue that the argument was the same, but the result differs, because the data type has changed.

Really, what determines if that is acceptable or not is your concrete use case. If you use the function in a way so that nothing breaks if you change the data type, it is alright to mark it as IMMUTABLE. If you use it in some other way, so that the changed data type breaks something, it was wrong to mark the function IMMUTABLE.
